# com.azure.core.exception.HttpResponseException: Deserialization Failed error in azurite docker image

Tags: java, azure, docker, azure-devops, jackson

I have been able to run the azurite docker container provided by Microsoft to run a local container of Azure Blob storage. Most of the time it works(when I upload images) but it fails when I provide other types of data. I get exactly the following error:

```
    Blob operation error on blob: 'reports/08191407-a4d4-4c86-9f3c-45a02b8c93ec'
com.azure.core.exception.HttpResponseException: Deserialization Failed.
    at com.azure.core.implementation.serializer.HttpResponseBodyDecoder.decodeByteArray(HttpResponseBodyDecoder.java:92)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.serializer.HttpResponseDecoder$HttpDecodedResponse.getDecodedBody(HttpResponseDecoder.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$mapNotNull$28(Mono.java:3429)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:176)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxHandleFuseable.java:257)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2068)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxHandleFuseable.java:161)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(FluxDoOnEach.java:173)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxDoOnEach.java:281)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDelaySubscription$DelaySubscriptionMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxDelaySubscription.java:189)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:174)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoInnerProducerBase.complete(Operators.java:2664)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:152)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1817)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:275)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:703)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'PK o': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
?u???\u0019+??a\u007Fi]??\u0012?d?F?_???6P?\u0002v??i?q?a?\u001C\u0013\u0017\u0006x\u0015???\u007F??\u00010?\u001E\u0000?\u001BJ\u0006??,?t??\u0019l?\u0013???/?~??Dj8I?
?\u007F?I?PJ?T?G?mkHr+???R&v\u001E?^Hk?\q?b;W????\u0015'-?s???)~???>?o?\u0014\u007FO)n? h?.?\u0012???'??\u001BC\u0003? I#\u0002?&i\u0007?#\u0013?\u0000\u001E???nxg?/??H???>??f?Y!\u000Er"[truncated 920346 bytes]; line: 1, column: 13]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2391)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:745)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3635)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2734)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:902)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:794)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4761)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4667)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3723)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperShim.readValue(ObjectMapperShim.java:224)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.lambda$deserialize$8(JacksonAdapter.java:225)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.useAccessHelper(JacksonAdapter.java:271)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.deserialize(JacksonAdapter.java:223)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.serializer.HttpResponseBodyDecoder.deserializeBody(HttpResponseBodyDecoder.java:145)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.serializer.HttpResponseBodyDecoder.decodeByteArray(HttpResponseBodyDecoder.java:86)
    ... 81 common frames omitted
```

I think this has to do with how the serialization is done for binary data but it is strange that such an error would happen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no problem with the code because the same code works if I test it with a real Azure system.

Answer (score 0):

i had faced this issue. it was due to version mismatch with dependencies. so add azure sdk as pom type.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.10</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

[link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/boms/azure-sdk-bom/README.md#adding-the-bom-to-your-project)